# How to package and upload an extension developed for Edge Browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I have been through the document and followed the "Menifold.js" Procedure. But after that also I am still getting some errors in my developer account while uploading the extension.

**Listing Some of the errors message**

1. Package acceptance validation error: com.microsoft.edge.extension is a reserved extension type. Your app does not have permission to use this extension type. To request permission, please use our extension submission form.
2. Package acceptance validation error: Apps are not allowed to have a Version with a revision number other than zero specified in the app manifest. The package Extension.appx specifies 0.0.0.2.

Comment: For #1, do you have a fully verified developer account? and have you obtained fullTrust permission for your package?

Comment: Yes i have a fully Verified verified developer account ,And I am not able to understand what is full trust permission for package. But I have followed all the steps listed in this page https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/blob/master/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/creating-and-testing-extension-packages.md @WarPro

Comment: Does your Extension use native messaging?

Comment: No This is a simple extension to set the home page according to their need @WarPro

Comment: You mean the page users are shown when they open a new tab or open a new Edge window? If yes, then as per Microsoft's Extension Store policy your Extension will not be approved for store. This is because the Extension should not override the "home" page.

Comment: @WarPro I think you do not have proper information about it because i have seen some of the extensions which are serving the same purpose in edge

Comment: For your reference "Breeze extension for Microsoft Edge lets users choose their new tab page" it is working fine in edge. I might be wrong please correct me if I am..

Comment: Yes. Also, Breeze is not available on official Windows Store because of the same reason. I never said it is not possible, I just wanted you to know that in the end your Extension might not be approved for MS store.

Comment: Then Now how i will make that abvailable for the users to use it

Comment: I am trying hard with them but I am not getting any answer from their side on mail or forum what should i do now. They are not even denying that i cannot upload such kind of extension.

Comment: As the Extensions platform is new. I think even MS is confused with the policies they've set. As your extension is clearly violating the Store policy, I suggest you to distribute it through other channels (Ex. your website) for now. When the policy changes you can submit it to store. There is not much you can do except this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..I will follow this only Thanks once  again